# From a visual studio package (VSIX) how do I detect a solution or project build?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-addins, vsix

From a visual studio package (VSIX) how do I detect a solution or project build?

Answer (score 4):

If you have a Package class in your assembly, you can do:

```
DTE2 = Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(SDTE)) as DTE2;
```

Then look at then IsOpen property, to see if the solution is open... the look at the Projects property to find the projects.

However, if you mean you how do I get an event when a solution is opened... then Solutions, for example:

```
public sealed class MyPackage : Package
{
  private DTE m_dte;

  protected override void Initialize()
  {
    IServiceContainer serviceContainer = this as IServiceContainer;
    m_dte = serviceContainer.GetService(typeof(SDTE)) as DTE;
    var m_solutionEvents = m_dte.Events.SolutionEvents;
    m_solutionEvents.Opened += SolutionOpened;
    ...

  }

  void SolutionOpened()
  {
     .... away you go...
  }
}
```

ref: VSIX: Getting DTE object ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.solution.aspx

ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte._solution.projects.aspx

Comment: Looking at this page on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.solutionevents(v=vs.100).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1; all of the events are labelled "Infrastructure. Microsoft Internal Use Only." Does that mean they shouldn't be used in a VS package?

Comment: I don't think this answers the OP's question (and I have the same question), which is how would one detect a BUILD event? You have shown how to detect a SolutionOpened event.

Comment: how do I access the compiled dlls (projects)? I'm writing an extension that depends on the compiled projects, that is, the extension will read metadata from the assemblies

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at `DTE.Events.BuildEvents` there are events for `OnBuildBegin` and `OnBuildDone`.